# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "caballito blanco" y otras equivalentes?

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa

Cuando a alguien que participa en un juego no se le podía eliminar o no se le aplicaban del todo las reglas -un niño pequeño, por ejemplo, que todavía no sabe jugar muy bien- le llamábamos «caballito blanco». Nunca había pensado que era un uso regional hasta que un día en el chat [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061?m=40092809#40092809) se mencionó «palomita blanca» y yo supuse por el contexto que se refería a lo mismo, pero también surgió la variante «cascarón de huevo».

Más adelante busqué un poco sobre el tema y encontré conversaciones en foros que mencionaban estas expresiones y alguna más: burrito blanco, gallinita blanca, azúcar...

Aunque no siempre, el adjetivo blanco aparecía en la mayoría de ellas precedido del nombre un animal en diminutivo.

¿De dónde viene llamar a alguien «[nombre de animal] blanco» para decir que es inmune a ciertas reglas? O si conocéis el origen de otras variantes también sería bueno saberlo.

Lo que he leído es de España. ¿Existe en Hispanoamérica algo similar?

Comment: @walen justo cuando iba a darle a enviar el comentario entra el tuyo con lo mismo que iba a decir yo... :-D

Comment: En México decimos 'de chocolate'. - ¡Oye, Luis! El niño si juega pero es de chocolate.

Comment: en mexico el "blanca palomita" no es enrealidad un termino para novato, si no para una persona que se deja engañar facilmente por su falta de experiencia, es un termino que denota pureza, inocencia y candor

Comment: tambien se utilizan otras fraces como "esta verde" para indicar su falta de experiencia,

estas fraces mas bien parecen jergas populares que varian en cada zona. 

su origen puede remontarse a la abundancia de ciertas cualidades del lugar donde se utilizan, pues ciertamente todos estos tipos de expresiones denotan cualidades propias de la naturaleza o culturales (las palomas blancas como simbolo religioso de pureza)

Comment: uno que se esta popuarlizando es el "te hace falta ver mas bax" XD

Comment: Yo he oído una variante de "cascarón de huevo": "cascarilla". (Andalucía)

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/420354/112436

Comment: Hay un juego algo viejo llamado ["Caballo blanco"](https://www.todocoleccion.net/juegos-antiguos/juego-aduana-o-caballo-blanco-componente-este-juego-5-cartones-~x14613067) pero no he encontrado hasta el momento alguna relación con la expresión

Comment: Hay tambien un montón expresiones con algún referencia al Caballo Blanco de Santiago (Santiago Mayor).  Paracen bastante antiguos ahora, pero permanecen en el idoma.  ¿Quizás están relatados?

Comment: Nunca he oído caballito blanco. Nosotros decíamos "ser huevito" cuando era pequeña.

Answer (score 3):

Por experiencia personal, en Panamá y ciertos países de Latinoamérica y Sudamérica por lo menos no se utiliza esta jerga en relación hacia animales blancos, pero tenemos una similar:

> Mantequilla

[Este articulo](https://elcomercio.pe/opinion/habla-culta/martha-hildebrandt-significado-mantequilla-149949) del diario El Comercio de Perú con referencias a otros diccionarios explica un poco sobre la etimología de esta palabra (énfasis mío):

> Este obvio diminutivo de manteca designa en la lengua general un “producto obtenido de la leche o de la crema por agitación o por batimiento, ya usando máquinas a propósito, ya mazando la leche en odres” (DRAE 2014). Pero en el lenguaje coloquial del Perú mantequilla también significa **“jugador a quien le hacen concesiones en las reglas de un juego, generalmente, por ser principiante”** (Diccionario de peruanismos, APL, 2016). El oficial Diccionario de americanismos (2010) consigna esta definición circunscrita a Nicaragua: “Persona que trabaja o juega en un equipo sin estar oficialmente registrado”.

Un ejemplo breve sería tal cual:

> Vale, jugamos con el hermanito menor de Juan, pero tengan en cuenta que el es mantequilla.

Comment: Interesante, la definición es exactamente esa que has puesto en negritas. Parece que cada sitio tiene su propia versión.

Answer (score 1):

Se trata de una expresión que hace referencia a todo aquel participante en un juego al que, por sus condiciones físicas, corta edad, inexperiencia u otras causas limitantes, se le ofrece la opción de no tener que seguir estrictamente las reglas de dicho juego, precisamente para compensar su *hándicap*.

De hecho, el Diccionario de la Academia recoge una acepción para **blanco**, que se usaba en el lenguaje de germanías:

> 12. adj. germ. Dicho de un jugador: Que por su candidez e impericia, resultaba fácilmente despojado de su dinero mediante trampas.

Al tratarse de un jugador con menos posibilidades, se le denomina con expresiones relacionadas con la **inocencia**, la **candidez**, la **pureza**, la **ingenuidad**, etc., que tradicionalmente se asignan al color **blanco**. De ahí que abunden las formas que incluyen este color:
caballito blanco, palomita blanca, borriquito blanco, azúcar, pan, huevo (cáscara).

Aunque el fenómeno se produce en todo el mundo, recibe innumerables denominaciones dependiendo del lugar. Por ejemplo, algunas de las formas que se dan en España:

- Albacete: azúcar, ir en azúcar, azucarillo
- Alicante: palomita suelta
- Almería: cascarón de huevo
- Asturias: cascarilla
- Badajoz: cascarón de huevo
- Baleares: mel y sucre
- Barcelona: sucre, azúcar
- Bilbao: caballito blanco
- Cádiz: cascarón de huevo
- Canarias: estrellita
- Cantabria: borriquito blanco
- Castellón: suro
- Córdoba: cascarón de huevo
- Granada: cascarón de huevo
- Huelva: cascarón de huevo
- Huesca: sucre
- Madrid: pollito, huevito, huevito de oro, huevo pocho, huevito duro
- Málaga: cascarilla, cuchara, cucharita
- Menorca: cul de botil
- Murcia y Cartagena: palomita suelta, palomita blanca
- Sevilla: cascarón de huevo
- Tarragona: sucre
- Tenerife: estrellita, violeta
- Toledo: caramelo
- Valdepeñas (Ciudad Real): pan y quesito
- Valencia: ir de bulto, suro
- Valladolid: caballito blanco, burrito blanco
- Otros: palomita coja, mantequilla

Answer (score 0):

En determinados ambientes, "Caballito" o "Caballo Blanco", designa a una persona que se dedica a prestar dinero, o a la que se recurre cuando el individuo no puede hacer frente a una deuda que tiene que pagar de forma inminente. En estos casos, se acude a este tipo de personas con el fin de que éste le respalde la transacción económica o deuda contraída. La cantidad del monto de la transacción económica, según los casos, puede ser grande o pequeña.

Recuerdo en 1960, cuando era pequeño en casa de mi tío Pepe, D. E. P. que escuché  esa expresión "Caballito Blanco", para referirse a una persona que ellos conocían.

Answer (score -1):

Sin duda este es un tipo de [jerga](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerga) que pasa a formar parte de algún dialecto regional según su popularidad.

Para denotar a novatos se han utilizado muchas palabras para indicar su falta de experiencia.
El uso de la palabra **blanco**, **pequeño** o **joven** son las características presentes de todo inexperto. En algunos lugares de México se les dice "Potrillos" a los que están aprendiendo algo nuevo, sobre todo si son jóvenes, en referencia a cómo los potrillos caminan torpemente al empezar a caminar.

"Blanca palomita" es otro ejemplo donde se hace notar la falta de malicia en una persona para notar timos. De ahí el viejo dicho "blanca palomita que te dejas engañar".

Y esto no se limita al español. Comunidades han utilizado otras palabras de otros idiomas según su uso : por ejemplo, "noob" para definer a un novato, una expresión extraída del inglés.

Comment: Creo que no hablamos de lo mismo. No se trata de novatos sino de personas a las que no se les aplican las mismas reglas, se suele usar con niños pequeños porque no comprenden el juego del todo para que no se frusten o esten todo el tiempo eliminados.

Comment: @walen Sí pero no. Está claro que generalmente son novatos pero no se les llama así por ser novatos ni tienen porque serlo. En un juego que conozca perfectamente un niño puede ser "caballito blanco" si juega con otros niños mayores ya que no puede competir en igualdad de condiciones.

Comment: Un ejemplo del ultimo comentario de @blonfu puede ser que la diferencia no venga del entendimiento, si no de diferencias físicas, como puede ser un niño jugando al futbol con mayores. Puede entender el juego a la perfección, pero aun asi se le podria llamar "caballito blanco".

Comment: como lo mencione en un comentario anterior :  su origen puede remontarse a la abundancia de ciertas cualidades del lugar donde se utilizan, pues ciertamente todos estos tipos de expresiones denotan cualidades propias de la naturaleza o culturales (las palomas blancas como simbolo religioso de pureza)